# bootstrap Cards margin don't working on jquery injected div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm injecting div's with bootstrap cards using jQuery.
it's working, but not the margin. I want put some space between the cards.
The mb-3 class is not working.
I need refresh the DO

```
   $("#output").append("<div class = card mb-3><div class = card-block><a href="+data[3][i]+" class=card-link><h2 class=card-title>" + data[1][i]+ "</h2></a>" + "<p class = card-text>" + data[2][i] + "</p></div></div>");
```

Thanks for the answers

Edit: Solution:

fix : div class = card mb-3 > div class = 'card mb-3'.

just added single quotes in the div class.

Comment: You can use browsers developer tools to analyse the styles for the cards and to experiment with the margin that should be added. The provided code is incomplete to make any analysis. To get a fast help - I'd suggest that you create [mcve].

Comment: Thank's. the tip you gave me work's. Just added single cotes to the  div class.